# Alter SQL Server 2008 Table Add Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with millions of rows. I need to add more columns to that table.

Is it better to set the recovery mode of the database to SIMPLE before altering the table, or does this have no effect on the operation?

Comment: Are you populating the column with a value? If so, is it a default value, or is it a persisted computed value?

Comment: Its a default value equals to ''

Comment: You may as well just make it nullable with no default value if a blank space is your default value...

Comment: If I make it nullable, do I need to set database mode to SIMPLE?

Comment: You do not need to set the recovery mode to simple. The reason we're asking is that depending on how you initialize the column, it may be almost instantaneous, or it may be a very costly operation. Without knowing more details, creating it as nullable should be the least intrusive way to initialize the column.

Comment: FYI, adding a NOT NULL column with a default constraint is a [meta-data only operation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130911/why-is-adding-a-not-null-column-with-a-default-constraint-instantaneous) in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition. SQL 2008 R2 support ends next year.